# How to adjust finger picks

Tags: acoustic-guitar

I started thinking I might get some more work if I developed my finger-picking abilities, so I bought some plastic and some metal finger picks. I can bend and shape the metal picks , but the plastic picks just let go of my fingers when I least expect it, and I need to adjust them to fit better. Anyone have a tried and true method to accomplish this task?

Comment: Do you know exactly what type of plastic they are? Some sort of heat like hot water should soften them up enough to mold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extended research, trial and error, and several mishaps, I was able to adjust my plastic finger picks by putting them in the microwave for just a few seconds. The plastic heats up quite fast and they can get too hot to handle, but they can be bent to fit your fingers and they will hold their shape after they have cooled back down.

Answer (score 2):

I have also used two sided tape (the kind that is for putting up plastic winter glazing on windows - very sticky) AND I also just found and ordered a bottle of sticky pick a liquid that performs the same function.  The tape I've used makes a huge difference in securing plastic picks to my thumb. For my fingers in the past year or so I've been using fake plastic nails.  That worked really great but my nails recently just colapsed due to the harshness of the super glue and now I have to find a finger pic ( I don't like the metal ones).